# Joint model for ordinal repeated measures data and MNAR dropout using R

Tags: r, categorical-data, repeated-measures, missing-data

I have a dataset consisting of repeated measures data of graded toxicity scores (0-4) in a large number of patients being treated with a anti-cancer drug. We would like to identify predictors for developing dose limiting toxicity (e.g. score 3 or 4).

Initially the dataset was analyzed using a cumulative link mixed model to identify such predictors (clmm in R package ordinal).

However, there is also informative dropout occuring in the dataset (MNAR), e.g. the risk of dropping out is related to the severity of toxicity. As this therefore may bias parameter estimates, it seems a joint model that includes a survival model for dropout would be best.

My questions are:

1. Is a joint model for dropout and outcome the only suitable option to account for dropout?  Or would there be other ways as well ? The only ugly alternative would be to analyze only the first part of the dataset, but I would rather like to use ALL the available data.
2. Is there an R package available that would readily allow such an analysis. E.g. longitudinal mixed-effect modelling of ordered categorical data, together with a dropout survival model. Or, alternatively, a mixed effect model logistic regression model with dropout (e.g. in this case we would reduce the dataset to having a dose limiting toxicity yes/no) ? The JM and joinR packages appear to be based on continuous data for the repeated measures.

Comment: In case you are still interested, I am developing those models.